# Grunt doesn't find package bower.json

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, bower, yeoman

I added a package (angulartics) and bower.json is updated with this package:

```
bower install angulartics --save
```

bower.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.3.5",
    "angular-cookies": "1.3.5",
    "angular-route": "1.3.5",
    ...
    ...
    "angulartics": "^1.1.2",
    ...
```

index.html:

```
<script src="bower_components/angulartics/dist/angulartics.min.js"></script>
```

app.html:

```
angular
  .module('lodgeoApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    ...
    ...
    'angulartics',
    ...
```

When I upload my app with "grunt serve" works fine but with "grunt serve:dist"
my app is uploaded but Grunt doesn't find my package (but find other packages) and I don't know why.

Grunt log:

> Running "cdnify:dist" (cdnify) task Going through dist/404.html,
>   dist/index.html to update script refs ?
>   bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js changed to
>   //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jqu ery.min.js ?
>   bower_components/angular/angular.js changed to
>   //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/ang ular.min.js ?
>   bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js changed to
>   //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/ang
>   ularjs/1.3.5/angular-cookies.min.js ?
>   bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js changed to
>   //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular js/1.3.5/angular-route.min.js
>   ? bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js changed to
>   //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular js/1.3.5/angular-touch.min.js
>   ? bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js changed to
>   //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jqu ery.min.js ?
>   bower_components/angular/angular.js changed to
>   //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/ang ular.min.js ?
>   bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js changed to
>   //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/ang
>   ularjs/1.3.5/angular-cookies.min.js ?
>   bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js changed to
>   //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular js/1.3.5/angular-route.min.js
>   ? bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js changed to
>   //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular js/1.3.5/angular-touch.min.js
>   ... ...

I think that my package should be showed in this log.

In browser console log:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)
>   http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angulartics/dist/angulartics.min.js

I think the problem may be on Gruntfile.js but I don't find it.

Gruntfile.js:

```
> // Generated on 2014-12-06 using generator-angular 0.10.0 'use
> strict';
> 
> // # Globbing // for performance reasons we're only matching one level
> down: // 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js' // use this if you want to recursively
> match all subfolders: // 'test/spec/**/*.js'
> 
> var modRewrite = require('connect-modrewrite');
> 
> module.exports = function (grunt) {

// Load grunt tasks automatically
require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

// Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
require('time-grunt')(grunt);

// Configurable paths for the application
var appConfig = {
    app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
    dist: 'dist'
};

// Define the configuration for all the tasks
grunt.initConfig({

    // Project settings
    yeoman: appConfig,

    // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
    watch: {
        bower: {
            files: ['bower.json'],
            tasks: ['wiredep']
        },
        js: {
            files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
            tasks: ['newer:jshint:all'],
            options: {
                livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
            }
        },
        jsTest: {
            files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
            tasks: ['newer:jshint:test', 'karma']
        },
        styles: {
            files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css', '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.ttf', '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.woff'],
            tasks: ['newer:copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
        },
        gruntfile: {
            files: ['Gruntfile.js']
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
            },
            files: [
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
                '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
            ]
        }
    },

    // The actual grunt server settings
    connect: {
        options: {
            port: 9000,
            // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
            hostname: '0.0.0.0',
            livereload: 35731
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                open: true,
                middleware: function (connect) {
                    return [
                        modRewrite(['!\\.html|\\.js|\\.svg|\\.css|\\.png|\\.jpg|\\.ttf|\\.woff$ /index.html [L]']),
                        //modRewrite(['^(.*)$ /index.html [L]']),
                        connect.static('.tmp'),
                        connect().use(
                            '/bower_components',
                            connect.static('./bower_components')
                        ),
                        connect.static(appConfig.app)
                    ];
                }
            }
        },
        test: {
            options: {
                port: 9001,
                middleware: function (connect) {
                    return [
                        connect.static('.tmp'),
                        connect.static('test'),
                        connect().use(
                            '/bower_components',
                            connect.static('./bower_components')
                        ),
                        connect.static(appConfig.app)
                    ];
                }
            }
        },
        dist: {
            options: {
                open: true,
                base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
            }
        }
    },

    // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
    jshint: {
        options: {
            jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
            reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
        },
        all: {
            src: [
                'Gruntfile.js',
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
            ]
        },
        test: {
            options: {
                jshintrc: 'test/.jshintrc'
            },
            src: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js']
        }
    },

    // Empties folders to start fresh
    clean: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                dot: true,
                src: [
                    '.tmp',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*',
                    '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git{,*/}*'
                ]
            }]
        },
        server: '.tmp'
    },

    // Add vendor prefixed styles
    autoprefixer: {
        options: {
            browsers: ['last 1 version']
        },
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
                src: '{,*/}*.css',
                dest: '.tmp/styles/'
            }]
        }
    },

    // Automatically inject Bower components into the app
    wiredep: {
        app: {
            src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
            ignorePath: /\.\.\//
        }
    },

    // Renames files for browser caching purposes
    filerev: {
        dist: {
            src: [
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
            ]
        }
    },

    // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
    // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
    // additional tasks can operate on them
    useminPrepare: {
        html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
        options: {
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
            flow: {
                html: {
                    steps: {
                        js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
                        css: ['cssmin']
                    },
                    post: {}
                }
            }
        }
    },

    // Performs rewrites based on filerev and the useminPrepare configuration
    usemin: {
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,**/}*.html'],
        css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
        options: {
            assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>', '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images']
        }
    },

    // The following *-min tasks will produce minified files in the dist folder
    // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
    // minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
    // to use the Usemin blocks.
    // cssmin: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
    //         '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // uglify: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
    //         '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // concat: {
    //   dist: {}
    // },

    imagemin: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                src: '{,**/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
            }]
        }
    },

    svgmin: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                src: '{,*/}*.svg',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
            }]
        }
    },

    htmlmin: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                conservativeCollapse: true,
                collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
                removeOptionalTags: true
            },
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                src: ['*.html', 'views/{,*/}*.html'],
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
            }]
        }
    },

    // ng-annotate tries to make the code safe for minification automatically
    // by using the Angular long form for dependency injection.
    ngAnnotate: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
                src: ['*.js', '!oldieshim.js', '!jquery*.js', '!storage.js'],
                dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts'
            }]
        }
    },

    // Replace Google CDN references
    cdnify: {
        dist: {
            html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html']
        }
    },

    // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
    copy: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                src: [
                    '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                    '.htaccess',
                    '*.html',
                    "i18n/**/*",
                    "dynamic_scripts/**/*",
                    'views/{,**/}*.html',
                    'images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
                    'fonts/{,*/}*.*',
                    'styles/{,*/}*.woff'
                ]
            }, {
                expand: true,
                cwd: '.tmp/images',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
                src: ['generated/*']
            }]
        },
        styles: {
            expand: true,
            cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
            dest: '.tmp/styles/',
            src: ['{,*/}*.css', '{,*/}*.ttf', '{,*/}*.woff']
        }
    },

    // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
    concurrent: {
        server: [
            'copy:styles'
        ],
        test: [
            'copy:styles'
        ],
        dist: [
            'copy:styles',
            'imagemin',
            'svgmin'
        ]
    },

    // Test settings
    karma: {
        unit: {
            configFile: 'test/karma.conf.js',
            singleRun: true
        }
    }
});


grunt.registerTask('serve', 'Compile then start a connect web server', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
        return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
        'clean:server',
        'wiredep',
        'concurrent:server',
        'autoprefixer',
        'connect:livereload',
        'watch'
    ]);
});

grunt.registerTask('server', 'DEPRECATED TASK. Use the "serve" task instead', function (target) {
    grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
    grunt.task.run(['serve:' + target]);
});

grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'clean:server',
    'concurrent:test',
    'autoprefixer',
    'connect:test',
    'karma'
]);

grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'wiredep',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'concat',
    'ngAnnotate',
    'copy:dist',
    'cdnify',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'filerev',
    'usemin',
    'htmlmin'
]);

grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'newer:jshint',
    'test',
    'build'
]); };
```

Comment: Dumb question, did you see if this path is correct: /bower_components/angulartics/dist/angulartics.min.js - Also is bower_components in the same folder as your index?

Comment: The path is correct and "bower_components" folder is in project root. My index.html is in "app" folder (project root).

The others packages are in the same path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I'm using "wiredep" for inject bower packages (you can see in Gruntfile.js). So, I must add my packages between "bower:js / endbower" in index.html and run "grunt wiredep".